# Laravel4: Fetching User data after successful login

Tags: php, laravel-4

After loggin a user, how can I load his data (I want to set his first name in the session)

```
    # Authorize user
    if ( Auth::attempt( array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']) ) ) {
        // doesnt work: $user = User::where('email',$input['email']);
        //
        // Load User details here and set in the session

        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Invalid User / Password' );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to retrieve the user id -

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

and this to get the user instance-

```
Auth::user();
```

It will return the instance of the logged in user.
If the first name field is save as `first_name` column in database, then you can get it like this-

```
Auth::user()->first_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a user is authenticated, you may access the User model / record like `Auth::user()`

For example `$email = Auth::user()->email;`

Check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users) for more